# EmguCV and multiple results with MatchTemplate

Tags: c#, opencv, emgucv

I'm using `EmguCV` to find a template in an image with the following code:

```
CvInvoke.MatchTemplate(image, template, result, 
Emgu.CV.CvEnum.TemplateMatchingType.CcoeffNormed);

double minVal = Double.MaxValue;
double maxVal = Double.MinValue;
        
var minLoc = new Point();
var maxLoc = new Point();

CvInvoke.MinMaxLoc(result, ref minVal, ref maxVal, ref minLoc, ref maxLoc);

if (maxVal > threshold)  
{
    // Do something
}
```

This works great, to get the best match.

But for some cases, I know that there are multiple matches and I would like to see all matches to later group them with `groupRectangles`.

How can I change my code to iterate through all matches?

******* UPDATE

I solved it with the following code, without understanding well what's going on, assembled from other small snippets I found. But it seems very clumsy, also, it seems to be getting lots of false positives, which didn't seem to happen when using the single match code. i.e., if a template is not in the image, the single match code didn't find it, but this code is finding lots of possible matches that are completely wrong. It finds the correct matches when they're on the screen, but with lots of other wrong stuff.

```
CvInvoke.MatchTemplate(image, template, result, 
Emgu.CV.CvEnum.TemplateMatchingType.CcoeffNormed);

// Normalize the result image into a matrix of floats (thresholds?)
Mat thresholds = new Mat();
CvInvoke.Normalize(result, thresholds, 0, 1, Emgu.CV.CvEnum.NormType.MinMax);

var rectangles = new List<Rectangle>();
var size = new Size(template.Width, template.Height);

// Convert it to a multidimensional array to be able to iterate through it
// (is it really necessary, isn't something native in EmguCV for this?)
var thresholdData = thresholds.GetData();
for (int y = 0; y < thresholdData.GetLength(0); y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < thresholdData.GetLength(1); x++)
    {
        var value = (float)thresholdData.GetValue(y, x);

        if (value > threshold)
        {
            rectangles.Add(new Rectangle(x, y, size.Width, size.Height));
        }
    }
}

var groupedRectangles = new VectorOfRect(rectangles.ToArray());
CvInvoke.GroupRectangles(groupedRectangles, 1);
var groupedRectanglesArray = groupedRectangles.ToArray();

foreach (var rect in groupedRectanglesArray)
{
    response.Add(new TemplateMatch
    {
        Position = new Point(rect.Left, rect.Top),
        Score = -1, // For multiple matches, I cannot find the score anymore, because they were grouped
        Size = size,
        Valid = true,
    });
}
```